# How to add default header and footer to a custom mail on magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, module, event-observer, email, custom

I have created a module where I send a custom mail.
For this, I have a custom email template.

Now what I want to do is to include the default header and footer that appears in all my Magento emails, in my custom mail.

I tried to include the header and the footer like this but is not working:

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
 ...content
{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

and my email_templates.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
        <template id="myid" label="mylabel" file="myfile.html" type="html" module="mymodule" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

I need to include also the header template and footer in my custom module because I think that my custom mail doesn't know what is header_template and footer_template? If yes, from where I can take this file and where I should put it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have created any xml file to call email template in your custom module.

Comment: see my upated question

Comment: plz show your php code which sent a mail.

Comment: have u run any commands after put your codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In place of {{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
you can use the its HTML code.

You can get the HTML codes for header and footer from this path:

/magento/vendor/magento/module-email/view/frontend/email

Place this code into your HTML file. May this works for you.